# Any Thunderbolt docks compatible with 4K at 60Hz?

Tags: dock, thunderbolt, display

I just got an Asus PB287 4K display.
I was hoping to use it with the [Belkin Thunderbolt Express Dock](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BQHD4B8).

The display works fine when connected directly to my 2014 rMBP, but with the dock it only gives a 30Hz refresh rate.

I spoke to Belkin and they said this was a known issue and would not work the the newer Thunderbolt 2 Express dock, either.

Is there any Thunderbolt dock that will work with 60Hz refresh and a 4K monitor?

Comment: I have the same problem having just got a belkin thunderbolt 2 express. 4k 60Hz does not work on the hdmi output, only 30Hz & with no retina scaling options, which is pretty useless for me. However it is correct that if you connect the 4k to the thunderbolt out, then you do get full 4k @ 60Hz. However, the problem there is you end up with no extra thunderbolt out, which may defeat the purpose of getting the dock in the first place, if you were looking to have two 4k monitors plus a spare thunderbolt out, say, for a drive; this won't work.

Comment: What's more, when I connect a 4k to the thunderbolt out on the belkin, while I do get 60Hz, the hdmi on the belkin is now switched off so an additional monitor is not an option in that configuration. (I had a further lower res monitor on there but have now had to move it back to the mac's own native hdmi out).

Answer (score 1):

I have an AMH 399U capable of 3840x2160@60Hz with its DisplayPort 1.2 input.

If I connect my AMH 399U to a Thunderbolt port on my Elgato Thunderbolt 2 Dock, with a DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort cable, I can then connect the other Thunderbolt Port on the dock to either my iMac15,1 (Retina iMac) or my MacBookPro11,3 (15" Retina MacBook Pro), and I get 3840x2160@60Hz on the AMH 399U, with either Mac, the same resolution and refresh rate that I get if I connect the Mini DisplayPort end of the cable directly to a Thunderbolt port on either mac.

I bought both the monitor and the dock on Amazon. They can be seen at [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00PAPMSLE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PAPMSLE) and [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00XTVGM7C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00XTVGM7C)